# Replicate cell format as well as value in referenced cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

I want to reference another cell, and display not only the value of the referenced cell, but also it's format.  For example:

```
If cell A8 contains `=B8`
  and B8 displays as `$1,234.56`
```

I want cell A8 to display `$1,234.56` and not just `1234.56`.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This post lacks details and is difficult to understand what you are describing. Please take a few minutes to explain what program you are using, the problem, what you have done to try to resolve it and where you are stuck. Then ask a specific question. If you need help, read [ask] in the [help].

Comment: If you Format B8 before writing the formula =B8, the cell A8 will be like B8 but if your format is after writing the formula it will not be reflected on the cell